# How to simulate existence of file to a particular process

Tags: linux, exec

Suppose I'm a user with no root rights on non-lsb Linux machine, where there is no `/usr/bin/env`. I would like to be able to call scripts that I download just as they are, to avoid editing them.

Can I possibly modify the behaviour of `exec()`, so if the argument is `/usr/bin/env` (no need to handle values like `/usr/bin/../bin/env`, it will call automatically `/some/writable/by/me/prefix/usr/bin/env`? Is this achievable?

Comment: Have you asked the admin to install it? What did they say?

Comment: @Nick I'm working on device with root access, but I'm aware that not every user of software that I'm gonna ship can gain root access.